# How to count records by store, day wise and in 2 hours range period with pivot table format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have multiple stores records with user's punch records.
I would like to create a report for each store' day-wise which 2 hours have how many employees was working?

```
Clock In ID Last Name   First Name  In time Out time
912 Bedolla Jorge   1/1/2021 7:29   1/1/2021 11:31
912 Romero  Gabriel 1/1/2021 10:55  1/1/2021 14:07
912 Bedolla Jorge   1/1/2021 12:00  1/1/2021 16:07
912 Zaragoza    Daniel  1/1/2021 13:06  1/1/2021 14:57
912 Thaxton Christopher 1/1/2021 14:01  1/1/2021 16:57
912 Jones   Elena   1/1/2021 14:01  1/1/2021 16:35
912 Zaragoza    Daniel  1/1/2021 15:12  1/1/2021 17:09
912 Jones   Elena   1/1/2021 16:45  1/1/2021 18:05
912 Smith   Kirsten 1/1/2021 17:30  1/1/2021 20:01
912 Zaragoza    Daniel  1/1/2021 17:41  1/1/2021 21:49
```

Looking for a result something like below. (below result data is incorrect)

```
store   ForDate 0-2 2-4 4-6 6-8 8-10 10-12 12-14 14-16 16-18 18-20 20-22 22-0
912 2021-01-01  0   0   0   1   0   1   2   3   3   2   3   0
912 2021-01-02  0   0   2   1   2   3   2   4   2   3   3   0
912 2021-01-03  0   0   1   1   2   2   2   2   3   0   2   0
912 2021-01-04  0   0   2   0   2   1   2   2   3   3   1   0
912 2021-01-05  0   0   2   1   1   3   4   4   2   2   1   0
912 2021-01-06  0   0   2   0   2   1   2   3   3   2   3   0
912 2021-01-07  0   0   2   1   2   1   3   4   2   2   0   0
912 2021-01-08  0   0   2   2   2   1   3   2   1   2   1   0
912 2021-01-09  0   0   1   1   0   3   1   3   2   2   3   0
912 2021-01-10  0   0   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   2   2   0
```

I tried to solve with below query but it's wrong and stil it's just inTime but outTime is pending.

```
SELECT TOP 10 store, ForDate, 
ISNULL([0], 0) + ISNULL([1], 0) AS [0-1],
ISNULL([2], 0) + ISNULL([3], 0) AS [2-3],
ISNULL([4], 0) + ISNULL([5], 0) AS [4-5],
ISNULL([6], 0) + ISNULL([7], 0) AS [6-7],
ISNULL([8], 0) + ISNULL([9], 0) AS [8-9],
ISNULL([10], 0) + ISNULL([11], 0) AS [10-11],
ISNULL([12], 0) + ISNULL([13], 0) AS [12-13],
ISNULL([14], 0) + ISNULL([15], 0) AS [14-15],
ISNULL([16], 0) + ISNULL([17], 0) AS [16-17],
ISNULL([18], 0) + ISNULL([19], 0) AS [18-19],
ISNULL([20], 0) + ISNULL([21], 0) AS [20-21],
ISNULL([22], 0) + ISNULL([23], 0) AS [22-23]
FROM (
select *
from 
(
  select store, CAST(InTime as date) AS ForDate, DATEPART(hour,InTime) AS OnHour, COUNT(*) AS Totals
  from Punches
  GROUP BY store, CAST(InTime as date),
       DATEPART(hour,InTime)
) src
pivot
(
  sum(Totals) 
  for OnHour in  ([0],[1], [2], [3],[4], [5], [6],[7],[8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13],[14], [15], [16],[17],[18], [19],[20],[21], [22], [23]) 
) piv 
) t1
order by store, ForDate
```

Here is SQL Fiddle with data.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jo4atDmmj8cshyK1CWWo7x/2

Comment: are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: Why are you using `varchar` for the `InTime` and `OutTime` ?

Comment: Answer can be in either should be fine.

Comment: @Squirrel It's just sample data import. but it will be DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

That is insane but worth trying

```sql
SELECT storeid, ForDate, 
ISNULL([0], 0) + ISNULL([1], 0) AS [0-1],
ISNULL([2], 0) + ISNULL([3], 0) AS [2-3],
ISNULL([4], 0) + ISNULL([5], 0) AS [4-5],
ISNULL([6], 0) + ISNULL([7], 0) AS [6-7],
ISNULL([8], 0) + ISNULL([9], 0) AS [8-9],
ISNULL([10], 0) + ISNULL([11], 0) AS [10-11],
ISNULL([12], 0) + ISNULL([13], 0) AS [12-13],
ISNULL([14], 0) + ISNULL([15], 0) AS [14-15],
ISNULL([16], 0) + ISNULL([17], 0) AS [16-17],
ISNULL([18], 0) + ISNULL([19], 0) AS [18-19],
ISNULL([20], 0) + ISNULL([21], 0) AS [20-21],
ISNULL([22], 0) + ISNULL([23], 0) AS [22-23]
FROM (
select *
from 
(
    SELECT [Dates].StoreId, [Dates].ForDate, Hours.hour OnHour, COUNT(*) Totals FROM (
        SELECT storeId, CAST(InTime as date) AS ForDate FROM Punches
        UNION 
        SELECT storeId, CAST(OutTime AS date) AS ForDate FROM Punches
    ) [Dates] JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)) hours([hour])
    ) [Hours] ON 1=1
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT * FROM dbo.Punches
    ) p 
        ON p.StoreId = [Dates].StoreId
        AND (DATEADD(HOUR, [Hours].[hour], CAST([Dates].ForDate AS DATETIME)) BETWEEN CAST(p.InTime AS DATETIME) AND CAST(p.Outtime AS DATETIME))
    GROUP BY [Dates].StoreId, Dates.ForDate, [hour]
) src
pivot
(
  sum(Totals) 
  for OnHour in  ([0],[1], [2], [3],[4], [5], [6],[7],[8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13],[14], [15], [16],[17],[18], [19],[20],[21], [22], [23]) 
) piv 
) t1
order by storeid, ForDate
```

Let's go a bit deeper:

I generated all possible dates by this part:

```sql
SELECT storeId, CAST(InTime as date) AS ForDate FROM Punches
UNION 
SELECT storeId, CAST(OutTime AS date) AS ForDate FROM Punches
```

And all possible hours by doing this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)) hours([hour])
```

Then I joined them to find all possible date-hours.

After that, I just joined them with punches and counted the punch if the generated date-hour is between `inTime` and `OutTime` by adding this condition:

```sql
(DATEADD(HOUR, [Hours].[hour], CAST([Dates].ForDate AS DATETIME)) BETWEEN CAST(p.InTime AS DATETIME) AND CAST(p.Outtime AS DATETIME))
```

The rest is exactly the same as your code

Comment: Thank you but "ISNULL([0], 0) + ISNULL([1], 0)" will not work. bcoz it will double hours for 2 hours range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple CASE statement to get what you so far try-

```
SELECT StoreId, CAST(InTime as Date) as ForDate,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (0,1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0-1],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2-3],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [4-5],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (6,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [6-7],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (8,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [8-9],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (10,11) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10-11],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (12,13) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [12-13],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (14,15) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [14-15],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (16,17) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [16-17],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (18,19) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18-19],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (20,21) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [20-21],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (22,23) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [22-23]
FROM Punches
GROUP BY StoreId, CAST(InTime as Date)
```

And for your final result use below query:-

```
         Select StoreId,ForDate, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN [0-2]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0-2],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [2-4]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2-4],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [4-6]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [4-6],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [6-8]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [6-8],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [8-10]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [8-10],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [10-12]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10-12],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [12-14]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [12-14],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [14-16]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [14-16],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [16-18]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [16-18],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [18-20]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18-20],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [20-22]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [20-22],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [22-24]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [22-24] 
     from
     (SELECT StoreId,FirstName+LastName as Name, CAST(InTime as Date) as ForDate,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (0,1) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<0 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0-2],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (2,3) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<2 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2-4],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (4,5) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<4 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [4-6],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (6,7) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<6 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=6)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [6-8],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (8,9) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<8 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=8) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [8-10],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (10,11) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<10 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10-12],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (12,13) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<12 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [12-14],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (14,15) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<14 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=14) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [14-16],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (16,17) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<16 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=16)   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [16-18],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (18,19) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<18 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=18) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18-20],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (20,21) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<20 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [20-22],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,InTime) in (22,23) OR (DATEPART(hour,InTime)<22 AND DATEPART(hour,OutTime)>=22)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [22-24]  
        FROM Punches 
        GROUP BY StoreId,FirstName+LastName,CAST(InTime as Date))  detailsQuery
        GROUP BY  StoreId,ForDate
```

Comment: Actually, after review, I found a small mismatch.

https://prnt.sc/yz9e96

Comment: https://prnt.sc/yzjq06

Need to go with a person too. Because the same person might check-in/checkout multiple times in the same time period.

Comment: I do small modification in my query. Ok, at first, can you please confirm if my query is ok if we ignore person? Suppose we have 3 field StoreId, InTime and OutTime. At first we need to solve this. Later we will consider person multiple entry.

Comment: Also , can you please tell my Why this entry not count for column [16-18] ?InTime='1/5/2021 16:49' and OutTime ='1/5/2021 18:32'

Comment: Because he is already there in time 14:44 to 16:39. So we don't count as the second person for the same time.

Comment: Ok I have updated query; now all should ok ,where if same person check-in/check-out multiple time then query will count 1 for same day. Also I have another question why this entry count for column [16-18] ?InTime='1/5/2021 12:57' and OutTime='1/5/2021 15:16'  .
                                                                                                                                   
As what I understood is that [0.00 to 1.59] is [0-2] ................. .....  and .......................[14.00 to 15.59] is [14-16] and [16.00 to 17.59] is [16-18]

Comment: Still result not working.
Here is the result: https://prnt.sc/zm9bhw